# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 using Boost Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, arm

I bought a new MacBook with the ARM chip and tried starting development on a multithreaded server using boost and c++, however I get a lot of undefined symbol errors when trying to compile. Every error has the above style with something not being defined for the architecture and being inside the Thread library.

I've checked for all the headers and correct paths and tried linking in the libraries boost_thread-mt.a and/or boost_thread-mt.dylib directly but nothing works.

All other includes from the Boost collection work fine.

I am using Xcode 13.1 and Boost 1.76.0.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <thread>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

const int max_length = 1024;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_ptr;

void session(socket_ptr sock) {
    try {
        for (;;) {
            char data[max_length];

            boost::system::error_code error;
            size_t length = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
                break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
            else if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

            boost::asio::write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(data, length));
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

void server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port) {
    tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
    for (;;) {
        socket_ptr sock(new tcp::socket(io_service));
        a.accept(*sock);
        //std::thread t(boost::bind(session, sock));
        boost::thread t(boost::bind(session, sock));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        server(io_service, 1234);
        
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()", referenced from:
      boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor> >), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor> > > > > >::~thread_data() in main-ec8ee2.o
  "boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()", referenced from:
      boost::thread::start_thread() in main-ec8ee2.o
  "boost::thread::detach()", referenced from:
      boost::thread::~thread() in main-ec8ee2.o
```

(It's of course a lot lot more but all the same pattern)

Comment: Have you built boost with your current tool chain ?

Comment: This is a linker error. You have checked the headers, but what about the libs? Make sure you have the boost thread module installed. Not all modules are installed by default and some of them are not header-only. If you still have the issue, pass the library path with the appropriate link flag.

Comment: As I've said, I already tried passing the correct boost threat library directly. Tough I am unsure what you mean with building boost.

Comment: @Chris Please share your compile command. It's not necessarily enough to specify the name of library to link. If the library is not installed in the magic system directory, you also need to pass the additional library path to the compiler with -L on gcc. This tells the compiler *where* to look for the libraries you name. Also please ensure the boost module you want is actually installed. Share the path to it here so someone can give you the proper compile command.

Comment: I don't have a make file because Xcode builds it for me, but I pass the include tags `-I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/lib` and the additional tags `-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/ -lboost_threat`

Comment: @Chris isn't that a typo in your boost library name?  Should be "thread" not "threat." And can you check your /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib dir to verify the lib is there? P.S. usually you can set Verbose and see the actual compile commands

Comment: yes of course, that was a typo in the comment. I verified it multiple times, the lib is definitely there

Comment: In order to know if this is a compiler setup issue vs. IDE setup issue, perhaps you could try running the compile command manually?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem